# A question on Mutually Exclusivity

Tags: discussion

Would questions of the mutually exclusivity of questions be better asked in Meta.Biology or on the site?

So lets say, one were to ask if two questions would generate mutually exclusive answers:

For example

"What is the evidence for Darwinism?"

And

"What is the evidence for Evolution?"

Comment: Could you maybe clarify this question, I'm having a hard time understanding what it's about.

Comment: I tried to clarify the quest

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What is the question you are asking to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about questions are by their very nature "meta" questions. So meta.Biology would be the appropriate place.

The [about page](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/about) discusses this right up front.

Honestly, your example questions aren't great examples for what you were trying to get at. "Darwinism" and "evolution" both mean many different things to different people. Many use "Darwinism" interchangeably with "evolution" so you'd have to set out and define each in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a question is "meta" doesn't mean it belongs here.  This meta site is for questions *about the site* and how it works, not meta-questions about Biology that are still themselves primarily biological.

If your question is best asked of a biologist, ask it on main.  If it deals with some issue that nobody outside StackExchange would have, it belongs on meta.